# JMM guarantees about reordering within a try-with-resource & JNI calls

Tags: java, memory, jna, java-memory-model

Given the following code sample:

```
 try (AutoClosable closable = new XXX()) {
      o.method1(closable);  
      o.method2();
 }
```

Does the Java Memory Model allows HotSpot to reorder `closable.close()` before `o.method2()`?

I deliberately ommit implementation details like *does method1 captures closable?* in the first part of this question.

---

My spefic use case is this:

I have a C library which can be summarized as:

```
static char* value;

void capture(char* ptr){
        value = ptr;
}

int len(void) {
    return strlen(value);
}
```

This native library is wrapped using JNA

```
interface CApi extends Library {

 static {
   Native.register("test.so", CApi.class)
 }

  void capture(Pointer s);
  int test();
}
```

And my original client code looks something like this:

```
cApi = Native.loadLibrary("test.so", CApi.class);


byte[] data = Native.toByteArray("foo");
Memory m = new Memory(data.length + 1);
m.write(0, data, 0, data.length);
m.setByte(data.length, (byte)0);

cApi.capture(m);
System.out.print(cApi.len());
```

The issue with this first version is that `m` has been allocated from Java and the lifecycle of this memory is tied to `m` being strongly reachable. `m` is no longer strongly reachable once `capture(m)` and memory will be freed when GC kicks in (JNA relies on `finalize` to free native memory)

To prevent this I proposed to subclass JNA's `Memory` to introduce an `AutoClosableMemory`. The idea is that using a try-with-resource construct would clearly state that the resource is strongly reachable within this scope. The bonus being that we could free the native memory has soon as we no longer need it rather than having to wait for a GC (hey that's RAII!).

```
try (AutoClosableMemory m = [...]) {
  cApi.capture(m);
  cApi.test();
}
```

Am I guaranteed that `m.close()` will never be invoked before `cApi.test()` and that `m` is strongly reachable? In this case `m` is captured by the underlying C API but the java compiler has no way to know it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, the JVM could reorder the instructions but the outcome of the method has to remain correct. HotSpot does not understand native code and in order to guarantee correctness, it never reorders code around native instructions.

Comment: I was looking for something like 'it never reorders code around native instructions' do you have a link for that?

Comment: Native code blocks are formalized as external actions in the JLS. They imply a happens before relationship with their previous and subsequent code. I once gave this presentation that you might find helpful: https://youtu.be/XgiXKPEILoc I talk about external actions at minute 40.

Comment: Thanks, excellent talk. I think you should add it to your answer. What you talk about [here](https://youtu.be/XgiXKPEILoc?t=40m37s) exactly addresses OP's question in detail.

Answer (score 1):

For one thread everything is guaranteed to run exactly in the same order as in your code(any reordering that does happen can in no way affect your program). Reordering can only affect how other threads see what happens. In your question there is only one thread so your program is guaranteed to invoke `cApi.test()` before `m.close()`.

Comment: That's my understanding too. However, I had like to understand what specifically prevent the compiler to reorder the close. From a Java point of view their is no dependency between the two statement thus moving the close would not break _as-if-serial_.

Comment: @ClémentMATHIEU Well, if it will affect your program then it *will* break as-if-serial. I will try to find something more specific but it's generally always true. This is not about Java point of view but the JVM and the CPU they know what they can get away with.